# Is there a way to know which mongoDB field in a document was updated last?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

For example, I would want to know which field was updated last for this schema:

```
  var blogSchema = new Schema({
    title:  String, 
    author: String,
    body:   String,
    comments: [{ body: String, date: Date }],
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    hidden: Boolean,
    meta: {
      votes: Number,
      favs:  Number
    }
  });
```

Comment: You'd have to explicitly record that information somewhere, MongoDB does not do it for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no built-in functionality that supports it.  You'll probably have to implement the logic yourself.